# Pick records n days after

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables in the below format

Table1

```
Date        IPOName   
01-01-2020   DUOL
01-20-2020   VAXX
05-01-2021   HOOD
07-01-2021   INST
```

and

Table2

```
CloseDate           SYMBOL    Value
01-01-2020     DUOL       100
01-02-2020     DUOL       102
01-03-2020     DUOL       120
01-30-2020     DUOL       110
03-01-2020     DUOL       150
04-02-2020     DUOL       110
01-20-2020     VAXX       50
02-20-2020     VAXX       100
03-20-2020     VAXX       150
```

Essentially `Table1` contains the date of an IPO and the stock ticker and `Table2` contains the daily closing price on a daily basis for each stock after launch.
I am looking to calculate a `Table3` as follows

Table3

```
Stock     30DayPrice    60DayPrice   90DayPrice
DUOL       110           150         110
VAXX       50            100         150
```

The `Table3` is essentially summarizing `Stock`, `30DayPrice`, `60DayPrice` and `90DayPrice` after the launch, with each launch being on a different date.
I  tried the use of `case` expressions with minimal success.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

My code is as follows:

```
with stock_list as (
    select IPOname, date
    from Table1 a
    inner join Table2 b on (a.IPOName=b.SYMBOL)
)
select IPOname
    , (case when dateadd('days',30,date)=CloseDate then Value end )"List30"
from stock_list
```

But I get only NULLS in the `List30` column
Thanks!

Comment: Using snowflake

Comment: Based on your sample date, you should be getting every record in Table2 with a NULL value for your case statement.  The reason is, there is no record in Table 2 that matches you case statement date value.  For example, 30 days from 1/1/2020 is 1/31/2020, which doesn't exist.  Also, your expected Table3 output appears to be an aggregated table, but your query isn't aggregating anything.

Comment: Thanks,This is a sample data I put in to represent the example. The entire dataset has a record for each date after the ticker listed. so for every ticker there is an entry at the 30 day mark.

Comment: you need to add `WHERE dateadd('days',30,date)=CloseDate OR dateadd('days',90,date)=CloseDate` ...

Comment: So, I'm not able to replicate your issue.  The code that you are providing doesn't execute at all, because your `stock_list` CTE doesn't actually output the fields that you are referencing in your final select.  CloseDate and Value aren't there.  This makes me believe that you are not sharing all of the code, which makes this hard to debug for you.  When I correct the code and use sample data that is complete, I get the correct value output.  I hesitate to put my sample in as an answer, since it's just fixing your sample code that doesn't execute.  I don't think that's your real issue.